# Error in optim: function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

Tags: r, optimization

When trying to use optim I got this error : Error in optim: function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

This is the function I use in optim :

```
stack_v = list(chlor_a = values(resample), layer = values(crop2))

min.RSS = function(data, par){
  sum(
    log(data$chlor_) - 
      (par[1]+par[2]*data$layer +
         par[3]*data$layer^2 +
         par[4]*data$layer^3 + 
         par[5]*data$layer^4)^2)
}             
optim(par=c(0.30963,-2.40052,1.28932,0.52802,-1.33825), fn=min.RSS, data = stack_v)
```

The initial parameters used here got an RMSE of 2.16 when using them so not too far from expected. Do anybody have a clue of what could be the cause of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by omiting the NA's values with this command :
 `sum(..., na.rm=TRUE)`